# What is wrong with this async code such that Babel throws and error?

Tags: async-await, babeljs

```
SyntaxError: C:/Users/Simon/git/reasondb/src/enhanceGenerators.js: Unexpected token, expected ( (17:11)
 15 |  generator[f.name] = async function(...args) {
 16 |     let result = [];
 > 17 |   for await(const item of generator) {
 18 |         const value = await item[f.name].call(item,...args);
 19 |         if(value!==undefined) result.push(value);
 20 |     }
 21 |  }
```

The above code works fine un-transpiled in current versions of Chrome and Edge. I would be perfectly happy if Babel just left it alone.

Comment: What version of Babel? Have you enabled async generator support?

Comment: "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-register": "^6.26.0" ... and I am targeting node v11.6.0. My understanding of using "env" as a preset is it should know that v11.6.0 supports async generators and I should not have to do anything else/